# How to add spaces in the first and the end of a string variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, arraylist

I'm trying to add spaces in the first and the end of this string variable, I tried to convert the string to an array, then add space with push() and unshift() ... but it returns "x.push is not a function"

```
function space_fb(x){
  x.split(" ");Array.prototype.slice.call
  x.push (" ") ; 
  x.unShift (" ") ;
  return x.join(" ");;
}
var xxx = "Medardo";
space_fb(xxx);
alert(xxx);
```

Comment: hmm `x=" "+x+" ";` ?

Comment: Quote: "my teacher wants it as a function ! – 15YO-m".  Such a sad, sad day when this happens.  Sorry - I'll delete my answer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this? JSON.stringify ist just to show the output in this way.

```js
var x = "foo";

function addSpaces(string){
  var a = string.split("");
  a.push(" ");
  a.unshift(" ");
  return a.join("");
}

document.write(JSON.stringify(addSpaces(x)));
```

Answer (score 1):

There is many ways this can be done you could simply add the spaces in your string value for example like `" Medardo "` and it will work, But My example would handle dynamic string data.

> You dont need that `space_fb` function at all its dead simple:

```
var xxx = " " + "Medardo" + " ";
alert(xxx);
```

> Edited as OP wanted it in a function as his "teacher wants him to"

```js
function AddSpaces(x){
   return " " + x + " ";
}   

var xxx = AddSpaces("Medardo")
alert(xxx);
```

Comment: Surely this is a simple case to demonstrate what OP's trying to do, rather than a real-world example of his intended usage.... if it was, why not just `var xxx = " Medardo ";` ??  Why waste time concatenating 3 string literals?

Comment: Very true but if his data is dynamic you would keep it the structure above @AlexMcMillan - sorry first comment i didnt see the rest of your comment ha

Comment: What if the string is `undefined` or `null`?  What if the string is empty?  What if the string is a number?  What if OP wants to use this function as a reducer?

Comment: i dont think he does hence his question did not ask that.. i cant prepare a answer for every situation lol @AlexMcMillan you answer a solution for them to solve and this above would handle dynamic string data.. if it is a number you can solve that easily but you probably dont want end spaces on numbers anyhow.. but that was not part of the question.

Comment: Is it possible to do that with a function ?

Comment: yes course it is but it is not needed.. why do you want it in a function @15YO-m?

Comment: Because "my teacher wants it as a function ! – 15YO-m".  I've deleted my answer.  @15YO-m: go LEARN how to do it for crying out loud.

Comment: i am going to help you because i feel bad for you here lol.. il update my answer now but i am so sure you could work this out @15YO-m

Comment: There you go @15YO-m hope you get a A*

Comment: @AlexMcMillan , U're rude .

Comment: @JoshStevens Thanks !

Comment: @JoshStevens it should be `return " " + x + " ";` still, you made my evening. @AlexMcMillan looks like a bad start of the day for you :D

Comment: ha oh lord what a mistake lol thanks @itsgoingdown that function was pointless otherwise.. i was just shocked at his comments of his teacher wanted it doing must of sent me stupid lol cheers

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are using method split but the variable is not being assign

you have two options

1.- x = x.split();

or

2.- var myArray = x.split(" ");

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering.
I tried what you said, but still doesn't work , it says :"TypeError: myArray.unShift is not a function"

I did :
function space_fb(x){
 var myArray = x.split(" ");
 myArray.push (" ") ; 
 myArray.unShift (" ") ;
 myArray = x.join(" ");
 return myArray;
}
var xxx = "Medardo"
space_fb(xxx);
alert(xxx);

Comment: is only the way you are writing it just use unshift in lower case and you will be fine, you can see it in this resource [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift)

Answer (score 0):

This is all you will need do not use the + + operators. A . is a concatenation operator.

```
  var xxx = ' '.xxx.' ';
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @itsgoingdown, in JavaScript you can append strings using the + operator. There is really no need to split the string into a character array and push/unshift to add spacing.

Answer (score 0):

```
function space_fb(x){
    x.split("");Array.prototype.slice.call
    x.push (" ") ; 
    x.unShift(" ") ;
    return x.join("");;
}
var xxx = "Medardo";
space_fb(xxx);
alert(xxx);
```